# How to iterate through the keys of a HashMap in order

Tags: rust, hashmap

I'd like to iterate through the keys of a `HashMap` in order. Is there an elegant way to do this? The best I can think of is this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut m = HashMap::<String, String>::new();

    m.insert("a".to_string(), "1".to_string());
    m.insert("b".to_string(), "2".to_string());
    m.insert("c".to_string(), "3".to_string());
    m.insert("d".to_string(), "4".to_string());

    let mut its = m.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    its.sort();

    for (k, v) in &its {
        println!("{}: {}", k, v);
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
for (k, v) in m.iter_sorted() {
}
for (k, v) in m.iter_sorted_by(...) {
}
```

Obviously I can write a trait to do that, but my question is *does something like this already exist*?

**Edit:** Also, since people are pointing out that `BTreeMap` is already sorted I should probably note that while this is true, it isn't actually as fast as a `HashMap` followed by `sort()` (as long as you only sort it once of course). Here are some benchmark results for random `u32->u32` maps:

[image: hashmap vs btreemap]

Additionally, a `BTreeMap` only allows a single sort order.

Comment: If you really want a `HashMap`, this is conceptually the best you can do. If you are fine using a `BTreeMap`, iteration will automatically be in order.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of `BTreeMap`, and I know this is algorithmically optimal. I'm just asking about coding ergonomics - is there a shorter more elegant way to write it basically.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`HashMap` doesn't guarantee a particular order of iteration. Simplest way to achieve consistent order is to use `BTreeMap` which is based on `B-tree`, where data is sorted.

You should understand that any implementation will do this in `O(n)` memory, particularly storing references to all items and at least `O(n * log(n))` time to sort data out.

If you understand cost of doing this you can use `IterTools::sorted` from `itertools` crate.

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.8.2
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut m = HashMap::<String, String>::new();

    m.insert("a".to_string(), "1".to_string());
    m.insert("b".to_string(), "2".to_string());
    m.insert("c".to_string(), "3".to_string());
    m.insert("d".to_string(), "4".to_string());

    println!("{:#?}", m.iter().sorted())
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a449c4fe8b1fd6c23721dff02bea4633)

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of `BTreeMap` - `Itertools` was the answer I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Also using `O(N)` memory isn't likely to ever be a concern because `O(N)` memory is already used to store the actual data. I would also expect the memory overhead of `BTreeMap` to that of storing `N` iterators. As for the time, sorting more than once is definitely slower but if you only need the data sorted once I wouldn't be surprised if it was very similar or even faster (depending on how it is implemented), since `BTreeMap` is effectively an insertion sort anyway.

Comment: @Timmmm "Insertion sort" usually means the O(_n_ ²) algorithm to sort an array in place. Inserting _n_ elements in a `BTreeMap` is fumdamentally different, and has a time complexity of O(_n_ log _n_). If you need the data in order even once, I'd go with a `BTreeMap` – it's definitely simpler, and likely faster as well.

Comment: D'oh, of course I meant tree sort! I'm not convinced `BTreeMap` it would be faster. Algorithmically they are the same complexity, and at least in C++ land, `std::map` can be very slow because it involves a lot of allocations. Maybe I'll benchmark it if I have time.

Comment: @Timmmm I'm also not convinced it's faster, but in the absence of a benchmark I'd go with the simpler solution. :)

Comment: Just did a simple benchmark, with 10000 random `u32` keys and values. `HashMap` (with `.reserve()`) followed by `sort` takes 1.16 ms, `BTreeMap` takes 1.47 ms, so I was right! Another reason to not use `BTreeMap` is that it only allows a single sort order.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what @Inline wrote, a more generic solution using `HashMap`, allowing for sorting by value and changing values. (Note that the content of the HashMap was adjusted in order to make the distinction of sorting by key and value visible.)

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;  // itertools = "0.10"
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut m = HashMap::<String, String>::new();

    m.insert("a".to_string(), "4".to_string());
    m.insert("b".to_string(), "3".to_string());
    m.insert("c".to_string(), "2".to_string());
    m.insert("d".to_string(), "1".to_string());

    // iterate (sorted by keys)
    for (k, v) in m.iter().sorted_by_key(|x| x.0) {
        println!("k={}, v={}", k, v);
    }
    println!();

    // iterate (sorted by values)
    for (k, v) in m.iter().sorted_by_key(|x| x.1) {
        println!("k={}, v={}", k, v);
    }
    println!();

    // iterate (sorted by keys), write to values
    for (k, v) in m.iter_mut().sorted_by_key(|x| x.0) {
        *v += "v"; // append 'v' to value
        println!("k={}, v={}", k, v);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=84ba7688cd98d609471f1f66bd7d6754)

Comment: Does anyone know how to sort by values and writing to values?